# Visual studio 2010 populating word template in c# error

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word

I have been developing my first application in Visual Studio 2010 and I cannot seem to find the solution to this problem. I am trying to modify a Word template and populate it with my own custom text. So I am using this code below to do so.

But every time I try the debugger stops at this line :`oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing).`

"COMException was unhandled. Word was unable to read this document.  It may be corrupt."

I have entered all the namespaces required and added references to word.
I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft Word 2007.

```
private void fnGenerateDoc() 
{
    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Object oTrue = true;
    Object oFalse = false;

    Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();


    oWord.Visible = true;

    Object oTemplatePath = "Test1.dot";
    oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

    foreach (Word.Field myMergeField in oWordDoc.Fields)
    {
        Word.Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
        String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

        if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
        {

            Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
            Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
            String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);

            fieldName = fieldName.Trim();

            if (fieldName == "NaslovFirma")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                oWord.Selection.TypeText("Nesto");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error message indicates that `Test1.dot` is corrupt. Is the file in the current directory? What happens if you double-click that file?

Comment: Have you tried with a blank `.dot` file? Also consider changing `oTemplatePath` to the absolute location of the `Test1.dot` file: for instance `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Test1.dot`

Comment: Test1.dot opens normally when I double click it. I have tried changing to absolute location but the error remains. I looked at the extension of the template and it seem it is .dotx not .dot . I tried changing the extension but I still recieve same error...

Comment: I think i figured it out, the template was saved as .dotx and it seems that visual studio can only work with .dot. I opened the tempalte in Word and saved it as .dot not dotx and it worked fine, Thank you all for your fast replies it helped me a lot :)

Comment: "Visual Studio" (you probably mean .NET or the Word OM actually) can both handle binary and OpenXML document templates. The issue most likely is caused by something different.